# Unity LoadScene too long

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making game with Unity and I'm using SceneManager.LoadScene for loading from main scene to play scene. Everything is fine, but it takes too long time. So, game move from main scene to play scene but there is a slider between two scenes.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Load : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Slider LoadSlider;
    public Text percentSlider;

    void Start () 
    {
        InvokeRepeating ("AdLoadPercent", 0.01f, 0.4f);
    }

    public void AdLoadPercent()
    {
        LoadSlider.value += Random.Range(0.6f,0.9f);
        percentSlider.text=Mathf.RoundToInt(LoadSlider.value*100).ToString() + " %";

        if (LoadSlider.value >= 1f) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scena1");
        }
    }
}
```

Why it take so long when my slider is equal 1?

" long " means that I have to wait more than 15 seconds.

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Also, you might want to stop incrementation if the value is >=1 because `LoadScene()` is called over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same without using the slider?

I haven't used `InvokeRepeating`, never even heard about it in fact, so there's a chance that there's something going on with this function.

Place `LoadScene()` line in the `Start()` function and see if this helps. If it switches scenes instantly (or almost, like in < 1.25s) it's a problem with your repeating function. For things like that I recommend using an `Update()` function or an `IENumerator`

Example #1:

```
bool loadingStarted = false;
void Start() 
{
    loadingStarted = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if(loadingStarted)
    {
        progressbar.value += Time.deltaTime*0.25f;
        //.. and so on ...
    }
}
```

Example #2:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Countdown());
}

IENumerator Countdown()
{
    while(progressBar.value < 1f)
    {
        //Do your incrementation here...
        if(progressBar.value >= 1f) break;
        return yield new WaitForEndOfFrame(); //or WaitForSeconds(0.05);
    }
}
```

Comment: you've never heard of `InvokeRepeating`?  that's amazing. it's maybe the most-used function in Unity.  it's great to know about coroutines, but it's remarkable to have never come across `Invoke` or `InvokeRepeating` !

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem when I put SceneManager.LoadScene ("Scena1") to start function.  I have one scene just with that slider, so main menu ->slider->play scene

Comment: Try adding the slider in the main scene. Create a prefab with a black UI image filling the entire canvas, and a slider in the corner or something. You can instantiate the prefab after pressing the button, and set its parent as such: `loading.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas"), false)`. That should work if the transition form main menu to slider worked instantly.